# multiprocessing.Value doesn't store float correctly

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I try to asign a float to the multiprocessing.Value shared ctype as follows:

```
import multiprocessing
import random

test_float = multiprocessing.Value('f', 0)
i = random.randint(1,10000)/(random.randint(1,10000))
test_float.value = i
print("i: type = {}, value = {}".format(type(i), i))
print("test_float: type = {}, value = {}".format(type(test_float.value), test_float.value))
print("i == test_float: {}".format(i == test_float.value))
```

However, the float stored in multiprocessing.Value is != the input float:

```
>>> i: type = <class 'float'>, value = 1.480021216407355
>>> test_float: type = <class 'float'>, value = 1.4800212383270264
>>> i == test_float: False
```

Whats the problem here?

**EDIT:**
Found the solution (see answers) However, I do not understand, why a "double" is the correct type here and not a "float". If someone can elaborate on that and include the solution, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python floats are `double-precision floats`, or what other languages would call `double`'s. That is why you need to use `'d'`: `'f'` does not correspond to the precision level python uses for `float`'s

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to set the `typecode_or_type` of `multiprocessing.Value` to be a double:

```
test_float = multiprocessing.Value('d', 0)
```

Allowed typecodes for `multiprocessing.Value`:

> ```
> Type code     C Type          Python Type     Minimum size in bytes
> 'b'       signed char     int             1
> 'B'       unsigned char   int             1
> 'u'       Py_UNICODE      Unicode character 2 (see note)
> 'h'       signed short    int             2
> 'H'       unsigned short  int             2
> 'i'       signed int      int             2
> 'I'       unsigned int    int             2
> 'l'       signed long     int             4
> 'L'       unsigned long   int             4
> 'f'       float           float           4
> 'd'       double          float           8
> ```

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array).

Comment: Python floats are double-precision